# laravel joined model has attribute but return null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables `schedules` and `reviews`.

`reviews` table has `schedule_id` column. so `schedules` table has many `reviews` and `reviews` is belonged to `schedules`.

And `reviews` table has many column including `review` column

When I send query using laravel model query builder, another column has well printed.
but only `review` column return NULL.

This is my code.

```
Schedule::join('reviews', 'schedules.id', '=', 'reviews.schedule_id')->first()->score
// It works well

Schedule::join('reviews', 'schedules.id', '=', 'reviews.schedule_id')->first()->review
// But It doesn't work.
```

When I dump `Schedule::join('reviews', 'schedules.id', '=', 'reviews.schedule_id')->first()`, that object has review column. So It was strange.

```
> App\Models\Schedule {#4373
     id: 1,
     date: "2021-06-27",
     modify_count: 0,
     state: "done",
     comment: "dasfsdfasdffs",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     schedule_id: 7,
     score: 7,
     review: "this is test review",
   }
```

Comment: Strange, but why are you using joins instead of the normal relation ?

Comment: If you do it by relation try this way. Since it's a One to Many relation: 
$schedules= Schedule::first()->reviews;
        foreach ($schedules as $schedule)
        {
            dd($schedule->review);
        }

Comment: Is that your full dump of the model? Model instances don't usually have the model properties directly on the object but rather they have it inside the `#attributes` property